# Avro can't read message with new enum value, even though default enum value was specified

Tags: java, serialization, schema, avro, json-deserialization

I have a base Avro schema with this enum:

```
enum ColorType {
    BLUE,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    UNKNOWN
} = UNKNOWN;
```

[The `UNKNOWN` value should be used in case an unknown enum value is encountered.](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#enums)

I have an updated Avro schema with the same enum, but extended with the `BLACK` value.

```
enum ColorType {
    BLUE,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    BLACK,
    UNKNOWN
} = UNKNOWN;
```

Now I try to read a JSON-serialized Avro message written by the **updated** schema with the reader of the **base** schema.

The java code looks like this:

```
var jsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(TreeRecord.SCHEMA$, resourceAsStream);
return new SpecificDatumReader<CategoryTreeRecord>(TreeRecord.SCHEMA$).read(null, jsonDecoder);
```

I get this error:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown symbol in enum BLACK
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readEnum(JsonDecoder.java:331)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readEnum(ResolvingDecoder.java:261)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readEnum(GenericDatumReader.java:268)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:182)
```

Why can't Avro deserialize an updated message with the base schema, even though a default value for the enum was provided? How can [full compatibility](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/avro.html#full-compatibility) ever be achieved with Avro schemas?

Comment: Avro 1.9.0 introduced `default` to `enum`. What Avro version does your reader program use?

Comment: @ChinHuang Avro 1.11.1 is used.